# Move (cover) file into folder with the same name at a different location

Tags: linux, bash

unfortunately I have not found a solution for this yet. I would like to run through a folder (incl. subfolders) to find all files with "cover" or "Cover" in the name and then move those into a folder with the same name as its current parent folder, but that new folder is in a different location. So

1st location:

```
/mnt/folder1/
-- subfolder 1
---- file.mp3 
---- cover.jpg
-- subfolder 2
---- file2.mp3
---- cover1.jpg
```

2nd location:

```
/mnt/test/folder2
-- subfolder 1
---- otherfile.mp3 
---- **cover from subfolder 1 goes here**
-- subfolder 2
---- otherfile2.mp3
---- **cover from subfolder 1 goes here**
```

The cover files should go from the first location to the second location. I have found out how I can find all the files (`find . -type f -name "*Cover*.*"`) but no idea how to move them, as I cannot understand, how I bring this command into the `"for f in *cover*.*; do"` format.

Thanks for some guidance!

Comment: First of all, I would consider  using with `find` the option `-iname` instead of `-name`,  because you want to catch _Cover_  and _cover_. Note that this would then also catch i.e. _coVEr_. If you want to avoid this, use `-name '*[cC]over*'`, which catches only the exact spellings you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With absolute paths:

```bash
src='/mnt/folder1/'
dst='/mnt/test/folder2'

(
    cd "$src" &&
    find -type f -name '*[Cc]over*' \
        -exec echo mv -iv -- {} "$dst"/{} \;
)
```

This will display the `mv` commands that would be run.

To actually move the files, remove `echo`.

---

It would be more common to use `while` than `for`. Something like:

```
find ... | while read var; do ...; done
```

`find`'s `-exec` option is like a better version of this as it is not broken by strange characters in the filenames.

Bash also has `nullglob` and `globstar` options which would allow a `for` solution directly:

```
src='/mnt/folder1/'
dst='/mnt/test/folder2'

(
    shopt -s nullglob globstar

    cd "$src" &&
    for f in **/*[Cc]over*; do
        echo mv -iv -- "$f" "$dst/$f"
    done
)
```

Comment: @thimplicity : This answer will print the commands to be executed but will not actually perform the commands. Look carefully at each command that is produced to ensure no errors will occur. You can copy/paste one command at a time to command line and ensure there are no errors or remove `echo` from the `find` command as now mentioned . Good luck to all.

Comment: I would drop the `-i` in the `mv` command. Most likely, such a script is supposed to run unattended, and asking the user for overwriting is contraproductive. If the OP wants to guarantee that existing files are not replaced, `-n` would be a better choice.